# Como passar dados lidos em um programa em c++ como momando no cmd

Tags: c++, cmd

Gostaria de saber como ler algo em um programa e passar esta leitura como um comando para o cmd, atraves da biblioteca stdlib ou cstdlib, tanto faz.
A foto mostra o que estou tentando fazer.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Leia [essa pergunta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/5483/132) e [essa resposta](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/5485/132) que nela está.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::string;
using std::system;

int main()
{
    string line;
    string command = "ping ";
    string param = "www.google.com";

    line = command + param;

    system(line.c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

Alternativamente, você pode [concatenar](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B) uma `std::string` e chamar `.c_str()` diretamente sem uma terceira variável temporária. Segundo [[class.temporary]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#4.sentence-3), o tempo de vida do temporário criado pela concatenação vai até o fim da chamada da função, portanto é seguro obter um ponteiro para o primeiro elemento da string com `.c_str()`.

```
using std::string;

int main()
{
    string arg = "www.google.com";
    system(("ping " + arg).c_str());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ainda bem que você não respondeu usando uma imagem no lugar do código. :)

Comment: @LuizVieira Haha! eu ia copiar o código dele para editar mas tive que escrever do 0. Ainda bem que é um código minúsculo.

Comment: Esperemos que ele(a) tenha aprendido a lição.

Comment: Gostei, uma vez quis fazer isso e não consegui...